# Images and products are not loading

Tags: product-images, conditional-loading, magento2.1.11

My website is on Magento 2.1.11 version I uploaded all the products and setting up everything but after that, I noticed that my website images (Banner as well as products) not loading in the first time. if I want to load them I have to refresh the page each time. even the products are not loading in first time every time I have to refresh the page then it works fine.

I tried all the commands like resize image, Upgrade, clean cash, reindex. I don't know what I'm missing.

Website link- http://oyekitchen.com

Comment: have you used porto theme?

Comment: Yes I used Porto theme

Comment: JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.andSelf() replaced by jQuery.fn.addBack() this is the error 
 solution for that @JugalKishor

Comment: try merging of JavaScript from backend and then check the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the known issue of porto theme, this issue is not related to Magento.
Follow below steps.

- Merge the JavaScript from the backend.
- Merge the CSS from the backend.
- Run command for content deploy after that.

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

- Flush the cache after that.

> php bin/magento cache:flush

Now, reload your page in private window now.